# Flutter - Moving JSON file from url to asset folder

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter, I need your help please. I am trying to move json file from url to asset folder, I could not factor what changes should be made to the code so that it can work.

I tried to fix it but I could not, appreciate if someone could help on this.

This is my code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'user.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(home: HomePage()));
}
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  HomePageState createState() => HomePageState();
}

List data;
List<User> userlist = List();
List<User> usersavedlist = List();
int index;

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'UserList Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('UserList Flutter'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.list), onPressed: _pushSaved),
          ],
        ),
        body: listView(),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<String> fetchData() async {
    final url =
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/highmobdevelopment/userlist/master/contacts.json';
    final response = await http.get(url);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('succesfull parse');

      this.setState(() {
        data = json.decode(response.body);
        data.forEach((element) => userlist.add(new User.fromJson(element)));
      });
    }

    return "Success!";
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  listView() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: userlist == null ? 0 : userlist.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[_buildRow(index, userlist), const Divider()],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRow(index, userlist) {
    final bool alreadySaved = usersavedlist.contains(userlist[index]);

    return ListTile(
      title: Text(
        userlist[index].name
```

Looking for your support please to get this resolved.

Comment: can you tell the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

you need to `await fetchData()` because it returns a future. Your `initState()` could look like this:

```dart
   @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
     Future.microtask(() async {
       await fetchData();
     });
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, What about this code   `Future<String> fetchData() async {
    final url =
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/highmobdevelopment/userlist/master/contacts.json';
    final response = await http.get(url);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('succesfull parse');

      this.setState(() {
        data = json.decode(response.body);
        data.forEach((element) => userlist.add(new User.fromJson(element)));
      });
    }

    return "Success!";
  } `

Comment: setState should be used to update the state and not make expensive calculations. see: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

can you please provide more information about the error you are getting?